# Is it possible to implement native methods in interfaces?

Tags: java, interface, default-method, native-methods

You often hear that methods in an interface have no implementation. However, in Java 8 it became possible to implement the default methods.
But I'm interested. Was and is it possible to implement interface methods natively? (`native` methods).

When the interview question is asked - "Is it possible to implement a method in an interface?" Answer - you can make a native method implementation, and since Java 8 it is possible to define a default method." How correct is this answer?

Comment: Have you tried defining a `default native` method in an interface to see if the compiler accepts it?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

No, interfaces [can't have `native` methods](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se17/html/jls-9.html#jls-9.4):

> *Note that an interface method may not be declared [..] with the modifiers `final`, `synchronized`, or `native`.*

Technically that text is non-normative, because it only points out that this list does not contain the mentioned modifiers:

> *InterfaceMethodModifier*:
>     *(one of)*
>     Annotation `public` `private`
>     `abstract` `default` `static` `strictfp`